# wordpress plugin generated 3 characters of unexpected output

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, themes

I created a widget, but when i activate it, i get the following message:
"The plugin generated 3 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin."

code:
http://pastebin.com/MgV2ZmjJ

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Kamera Widget
Description: kamera
*/

class KameraRa extends WP_Widget {

function __construct() {
parent::__construct(

'KameraRa',

__('Kamera', 'wpb_widget_domain'),

array( 'description' => __( 'Kamera v živo', 'wpb_widget_domain' ), )
);
}

public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
$title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );   
echo $args['before_widget'];
if ( ! empty( $title ) )
echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];


echo __( '<a target="_blank" href="http://www.ex.com">        
                        <center><img width="100%" src="http://ex2.com" alt="RTC Kranjska Gora - Kekec"></center>
                </a>', 'wpb_widget_domain' );
echo $args['after_widget'];
}

public function form( $instance ) {
if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
$title = $instance[ 'title' ];
}
else {
$title = __( 'Snežni park v živo', 'wpb_widget_domain' );
}
?>
<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
</p>
<?php
}


public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
$instance = array();
$instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
return $instance;
}
}


function wpb_load_widget() {
        register_widget( 'KameraRa' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_load_widget' );
?>
```

I tried removing all blank spaces around `<?php` and   `?>`, but it doesnt help.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was UTF-8 encoding. I converted the files to ANSI and the problem is gone.

Found the answer here:
https://www.toddlahman.com/the-plugin-generated-x-characters-of-unexpected-output-during-activation/

Answer (score 0):

1) Please remove extra spacing in the inner pages or plugin pages.

2) remove the inline styling in the pages or plugin pages.

its worked for me everytime. i have used many times same method. when the problem error in the plugin page or Wordpress page.

Regards,

Hitesh Nagpal